# Vue.js - Post method not working when pressing button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component, pug

Whenever I try to click on the button it doesn't add any records. But when I put on the input field `@keyup.enter="addusers"` Then it's working when I press enter. I want it to work with Add button. Can someone give me advice.

```
.row
      input(type='text', v-model='newUser')
      input(type='text', v-model='newMail')
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='button' @onclick="addUsers") Add

        
      .col-lg-12.text-left(v-for="user in users")
        p {{ user.name}}- {{user.email}}
```

```
 addUsers() {
      axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
        name: this.newUser,
        email: this.newMail
      })
      .then(({data}) => {
        this.users.push(data);
       
      });
```

Comment: Typo. "@click" instead of "@onclick"

Answer (score 1):

the click event should be written `@click` instead of `@onclick`

```
 button.btn.btn-primary(type='button' @click="addUsers") Add
```